# Using a callback function to find the sum of values in a bst (without a global)

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I've got a binary search tree full of objects. I'm traversing the tree using a callback function that adds a property of all the objects to a global variable. I've got this working, but I'd like to find a way to accomplish this without using a global.

Here's the relevant code:

```
TOTAL_AGE = 0.0

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data


class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def traverse(self, callback):
        self._traverse(callback, self.root)

    def _traverse(self, callback, node):
        if node is None:
            return
        self._traverse(callback, node.left)
        callback(node.data)
        self._traverse(callback, node.right)


def add_ages(tree):
    tree.traverse(callback)


def callback(student):
    global TOTAL_AGE
    TOTAL_AGE += student.age


def main():
    tree = bst.Tree()
    add_ages(tree)
    print TOTAL_AGE
```

This is admittedly for an assignment, which requires that I use the current traverse function and not a different implementation. That's mainly my issue though because I don't see a way to do this without using a global or modifying traverse().

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a method of a class instance as callback so that you can keep track of the state in the instance:

```
class Count(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.total_age = 0
    def callback(self, student):
        self.total_age += student.age
```

And then instantiate `Count` and pass its `callback` method to the `Tree`:

```
count = Count()
tree.traverse(count.callback)
```

Comment: Not as elegant as I was hoping for, but a great solution nonetheless. Thanks!